# std::distance goes wrong for unordered map

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap, unordered-multiset

What's wrong with `std::distacne` in this [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/eG4q4643a)?

As far as I know, for `std::map` or `std::vector`, it's ok to invoke `std::distance`.
But for this code snippet, the program will break down if `std::distance` is called.

```
// constructing unordered_multisets
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

int main ()
{
std::unordered_multiset<std::string> sixth ( {"red","green","blue"} ); // range


auto itr = sixth.begin();
itr++;


int dis = std::distance(itr, sixth.begin()); //What's wrong?!
std::cout << ">>"<< dis << std::endl;

std::cout << "game over" << std::endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: `std::distance(sixth.begin(), itr)`, voting to close as a typo.

Comment: The order of parameters for std::distance is wrong

Comment: @ArminMontigny Could you please explain that in more detail for me?